# $.ajax not hitting controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

this is my sample code:

```
 $("#btnPost").click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax(
       {
        url: "/api/Flight/FlightList",
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'TokenId': $("#pageInitCounter").val() }, true),
       //  data:"",
         success: function (data) {
           // implementation here
          ........................
```

As, u can see if i click button then it should hit controller and post the form data but it is not working.it was working fine in older chrome version.

but yesterday i updated my chrome browser. after that its not working.
if i try this:

```
 data:"",
```

then it is hitting controller but with empty data. how it should be done.please someone tell me.

i am using jquery version 1.9.1

Comment: is it sync request or async?, if it sync then try making it async, by adding option async: false, after dataType

Comment: Need to inspect actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. look at what is being sent, status etc

Comment: Try with full url and type: 'post' not 'Post'.

Comment: @Prs `type` gets normalized internally

Comment: is it working in other browsers?

Comment: async: true did the trick @ParagBhayani

Comment: @duke: added as answer!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ajax operation just add

async: true,

after

datatype: "json",

and that should solve your problem. Chrome has issue handling asynchronus calls.

```
 $("#btnPost").click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax(
       {
        url: "/api/Flight/FlightList",
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        data: $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'TokenId': $("#pageInitCounter").val() }, true),
       //  data:"",
         success: function (data) {
           // implementation here
          ........................
```

Note: async parameter is bydefault true, so you need not pass that with request, so removing async: false will also do it for you.

Comment: This is so wrong!!! `async: false` is deprecated by browser vendors and is  a terrible practice.

Comment: @charlietfl: Indeed, I wrote false by mistake ;)

Comment: @charlietfl: Yahh, that is true, but it solved problem for OP as somehow bymistake he passed false, so just to make him understand